# IC has pull-down resistors on SMBus lines?

Tags: i2c, smbus

The datasheet of TI bq40z50-R2 (Li-Ion Battery Pack Manager) tells that "The SMBus clock and data lines have internal pulldown".

Pin equivalent Diagram is in image below:
[image: Pin equivalent Diagram]

Aren't usually the SMBus Data and Clock lines to be connected to pull-up resistors?

I'd like to connect this IC and a Battery Charger IC to same SMBus, but the latter requires pull-up resistors for the SMBus lines.

Would this work anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The internal pull-downs in question are very weak, 1 MΩ. They are not meant to be "operational", and won't have any effect on normal I2C data transactions when the standard (10k-5k or 2k) pull-ups are attached to the I2C system bus. The reason for weak pull-downs is to provide well-defined bus state during power-on transients, when not all parts of the system are yet powered up.

The initial state with pull-downs is used by internal logic of the IC, per datasheet P.34:

> When the gas gauge senses that both lines are low (such as during
>   removal of the pack),the device performs auto-offset calibration and
>   then goes into SLEEP mode to conserve power"

Comment: Just a tip: you can use HTML symbols in the posts. `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, etc. For superscripts and subscripts use HTML `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>`. They don't work in the comments.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Transistor, thanks, and don't delete your comment - I will use it as future guide:-)